# Size of ToolTip message should remain same for the different system DPI settings

Tags: c#

When the user changes the system DPI settings(Normal Size 96 DPI , Large Size 120 DPI etc), the tooltip message is also impacted/changed. But as per our requirement tooltip message shouldn't change its size.

I was able to set different size and font of Tooltip message and its popup through it's events like Draw and Popup. I also changed AutoScaleMode to DPI/Font/None. But still expected result/display not occur.  I also set the Autosize and Autoscalling but those are useful only for the other controls(listview, label etc) not for tooltip. Kindly help me for this scenario.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This is an all-around drastically bad idea.  It is not impossible, you have to custom-draw the tooltip and use a *smaller* font size so it can still fit the tooltip window.  But this just collapses into a hopeless mess on "retina" monitors with a DPI of 220 or better.  You get to choose between very ugly pixelated text or a tooltip window that's readable only with a magnifying glass.

Comment: this isnt logical!! why would you like to do it?

Comment: our application required it. All the text are in constant size.